# JDK 9 unsafe import sun.misc.Launcher

Tags: java, java-9, getresource

I've recently upgraded to JDK 9 and Eclipse complains that `sun.misc.Launcher` cannot be imported. It seems that `sun.misc.Launcher` is unsafe.
I'm looking for an alternative to replace this line of code in my project.

```
final URL url = Launcher.class.getResource("/");
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Update: the more complete version of the above block of code is:

```
final URL url = Launcher.class.getResource("/");
final File fs = new File(url.toURI());
for (File f : fs.listFiles()) {
     System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

This is to print all the files in the `src` folder when program is launched in IDE.

Comment: could you add to the details what are you ultimately trying to achieve using the above line of code?

Comment: heya, JDK 9 have several ['internal' api restricted](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/260) from external access.. you will need to find a replacement for it.

Comment: sun.misc.Launcher was a JDK internal class in JDK 8 and older to create the built-in class loaders and so other initialization prior to calling your main method. The class does not exist in JDK 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Class.getResource` method can be invoked on any `Class`

```
final URL url = ClassInTheCurrentModule.class.getResource("/");
```

**UPDATE**

Edited based on Feedback from members

Comment: ClassLoader.class.getResource("/") returns null unfortunately.
Though MyClass.class.getResource("/") works perfectly.

Comment: ClassLoader returns null, so does Object, so I guess the class has to come from my src folder.
Sorry if the following doesn't answer the question since I'm not an expert on this, but MyClass is the class in which the above code resides. I also tried replacing MyClass by other classes in my src folder and it works too.

Comment: And that has been working since Java 1.1; there never was a reason to use the private, implementation-specific `sun. …` class.

Answer (score 3):

Calling the [`Class.getResource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) from any of the class in the module whose classes are being tried to access should work fine.

```
final URL url = ClassInTheCurrentModule.class.getResource("/");
```

The reason why the [answer by shazin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47645976/1746118) might return `null` is probably that with `ClassLoader` being a caller for the `getResource` call:

> returns `null` when the resource is a non-".class" resource in a package
>   that is not open to the caller's module.

Since `ClassLoader` belongs to the package `java.lang` in the module `java.base` to which your module might not be open.

Also, do note the resolution of the `getResource` is split further for named and unnamed modules.

Comment: nullpointer is correct. If the resource is something that is included with your library or application when Class.getResource is the API to locate it. If you are looking to scan the class path for a resource that some other library or application includes then you use ClassLoader.getResource.